# Link to index.html Javascript/Phonegap

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova

I do use http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/05/navigation-bar-with-nativecontrols-in-cordova/ and the latest Version of Cordova and Xcode. I find the function in Javascript, take a look down under.

How can I link do index.html?

```
function onLeftNavButton() {
    window.location("index.html");
}
```

`window.location("file://www/index.html");`, `window.location("file://index.html");` `window.location("./index.html")`; Don't work either and if I do `window.loction.href` don't work too.

If I do an `alert("123");` it is working fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is

```
windows.location.href = "index.html";
```

Cheers.